# How to find k-length path with minimum weight?

Tags: algorithm

Given V vertices : V1,V2,V3....,V300. There exists an edge from Vi to Vj for all i less than j and we are given weight of each such edge. We have to find k-length path (ie visited exactly k vertices)  starting from V1 and can end at any other vertex such that weight is minimum.

I have tried Bruteforce with dp which gives me O(2^n) which is slow.

Comment: Please could you work on improving the clarity of your question. Right now it reads like you're looking to find a path -- any path -- starting from V1 and ending anywhere that traverses any `k` nodes and has any weight.

Comment: @NPE :I have edited question , please see if you can now understand it :)

Comment: Hmm, dp should be enough with this state `dp[k][vertice index]` why do you think it is O(2^n)? I think it is O(k*n^2), can you show us your code?

Comment: Is the graph directed?

Comment: @user2040251 I think yes, `an edge from Vi to Vj for all i less than j`

Comment: @MaggiIggam Look at user2040251's answer, I think it is correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that your graph is acyclic to get a dynamic programming solution with `O(n ^ 3)` time complexity.

Let's assume that `f(v, length)` is the minimum weight of the path that ends in the `v` vertex and contains exactly `length` vertices. Initially, `f(v, 1) = 0` for all `v`(because a path with exactly one vertex has weight `0`). Then you can iterate over all vertices from `1` to `n` to compute `f` values:

```
for i = 1 ... n
    for j = 1 ... i - 1
        for length = 1 ... k
            f(i, length + 1) = min(f(i, length + 1), f(j, length) + dist(j, i))
```

The answer is `min(f(v, k))` for all `v`.

Comment: This algorithm has the correct idea but is wrong i suppose. Why are you using 'max' in last line? And also the 3rd loop should be the first one? Before and after doing these corrections too i am getting Wrong Answer.

Comment: @MaggiIggam Yes, it should be min. The order of loops does not matter. i should go from 1 to n, too. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Can you just tell me one last thing that why you mentioned 'graph is acyclic' why do we need that condition?

Comment: @MaggiIggam If a graph had cycles, it would be impossible to make sure that there is no vertex which was visited two or more times(it would require storing a mask of visited vertices).